# What are the key differences between working on Xamarin Form and working on Native mobile app developement?

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I have been learning to work on Xamarin Form. However, passing hard time to figure out the key advantages of using Xamarin Form.

Comment: Your question is rather broad and mostly opinion based but I hope I can help you giving my vision. With Xamarin (and Forms) you can make use of the so called Write Once, Run Anywhere method. You just have to write your code once and it runs on the three major app platforms (and some others). If you would want to do that natively, you would have to write a Android (with Java), iOS (with Objective-C or Swift) and WinPhone (in C#) app seperately and put three times the effort in it to create the same app. Not to mention maintainability. That is the short answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, that I understood. Actually, I would like to know if there is any syntax difference between them.

Comment: That depends. For Windows Phone? No. For iOS and Android, well, not just a syntax difference, but you are using a completely different language and framework. Like I said if you want to create native apps in iOS you would have to use Xcode (Visual Studio like) and Objective-C (C++ like) and for Android you would use Eclipse (Visual Studio like) and Java (syntax related to C#, but completely different). Also for Forms your would use XAML which is somewhat related to the AXML in Android, but has a different structure. So short answer; the differences are huge, like English and Spanish.

Answer (score 2):

**Xamarin.Forms adds a layer of *abstraction* on top of Xamarin's native APIs.**

Xamarin gives you access to the native API for each platform. But because Xamarin.Forms is an abstraction on top of those native APIs, the Xamarin.Forms API is, by definition, *different* from core Xamarin.

The key benefit to using Xamarin.Forms is sharing UI code. With vanilla Xamarin, your core application logic is shared across platforms, but your UI code is platform-specific. With Forms, you write your UI in genericized XAML, and Xamarin.Forms translates that to a native UI for you. In the end, for a *simple* application with no serious platform differences, you can achieve very close to 100% code sharing across the three Xamarin platforms (iOS, Android, Windows).

It is worth noting that though Xamarin.Forms gives you the power to not write a single line of platform-specific code, it also gives you the flexibility to write platform-specific code when needed. In practice, this means that in the areas that the Forms team has not yet provided a common abstraction for a native API feature, you can easily write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Like Gerald wrote, there are huge differences between the developing environments.
I work with .forms since about 8 months now and are short before ship my app's (**iOS, Android and Windows Phone**) to the stores.
**So the (very!) big advantage with .forms is, that I have ONE project with about 98% identical code and be able to release my app for all three platforms.**
Actually, .forms is on the way to (soon) support also WP 8.**1** and **Windows** (whereby Windows is a **new** platform what brings you additional benefits to work with .Forms).
As I have started, there were various bugs and disadvantages in .forms (as it is a very **young** platform). Especially with the latest releases it has become better and more stable (so that I can release my apps for production).
The problem is, that actually still some features are missing in the XF-implementation. The good is, that there are some add-ons out there (like XLabs) that you can use to extend the functionality and you also **can** implement your **own** platform code (especially to iOS and/or Android and/or Windows Phone).
**So the (my) bottom line is:**
With .forms you can save a lot of time to develop app's for **multiplatform.**
**As you are on the way to learn XF already, I would go further with it.**
Your further have the option to change to the platform-versions (Xamarin.ios / Xamarin.Android) if you should find insuperable obstacles...